# How can I retrieve mention entities from a Microsoft Teams message as well as LUIS intent entities?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot that I'm currently working on that takes advantage of the `LuisRecognizer` to match intents defined in my model. The initial message that kicks off the bot uses a mention to identify the target of the subsequent action.

The LUIS model correctly identifies the subject of the intent but their entity obviously only references the raw string value of the identified user. From the documentation, I am told that the original message should have an entities array of its own that includes the original mentions. I should be able to access this on `session.message.entities` from within my NodeJS bot implementation. However, `session.message` does not exist on ANY incoming message that was matched against a LUIS intent.

How can I retrieve the original message's entity list?

Here is how my bot is initialized:

```
const recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(config.get('bot.model'))
const intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })

intents.matches('reward', '/reward')
bot.dialog('/', intents)

bot.dialog('/reward', [(session, context, next) => {
  // session.message does not exist here
}])
```

Comment: That's strange. Can you compare your code against https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS/app.js to see if you find any major difference there?

Comment: @EzequielJadib edited the original to include an example of how my bot is initialized. That seems to be the only substantive difference between our two codebases. I'll give your style a shot.

Comment: BTW, the sample is using botbuilder v3.7.0 (just in case), that's why we are using the new style.

Comment: Excellent, perhaps the example I was referencing is outdated. Just out of curiosity, what qualities identify it as the newer version? The use of the `.triggerAction()` chains, etc? Is IntentDialog deprecated?

Comment: It worked? Can i post something along the lines we discussed as an answer? I don't recall in which version the new style was added; it was prior to v3.7 for sure. Things I remember are: not using / in the dialogs anymore, using triggerAction, intentDialog is not deprecated, I think that LuisDialog is it.

Comment: v3.5.3 was the version and the deprecated things are https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node/core/src/deprecated

Answer (score 4):

To address your question regarding the entity list, have you attempted using context.entities instead of session.message.entities? While session.message does have an 'entities' property, the session object itself doesn't receive data from the LUIS call unlike your context object.

The context (or *args,* or *results*) object you passed in as your second parameter in the waterfall step contains the intents and entities generated from LUIS.

I've created a bot that incorporates Cortana's prebuilt alarm app for its LUIS app. Below is the code for the 1st waterfall step of the dialog '/set_alarm'. It will console log the session.message and context object (called args here) from the LUIS call:

```
bot.dialog('/', intents);
intents.matches('builtin.intent.alarm.set_alarm', '/set_alarm');

bot.dialog('/set_alarm', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        if (session.message) {
            console.log('===\n1st waterfall step, session.message object found:');
            console.log(session.message);
        } else {
            console.log('session.message object not found.');
        }
        if (args) {
            console.log('===\nargs object found:');
            console.log(args);
        }
        ...
    }, 
    // additional waterfall steps
])
```

Here is the output of the console output of [the 1st waterfall step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5YUS.png). This is a [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqPtu.png) of the chatbot interactions via the emulator.

If you're still having issues could you log your context object so we could see what it contains?
Regarding the lack of a session.message object, are you receiving any error messages? Your posted code doesn't look to have any problems.

You can find the repo for this chatbot on github here: https://github.com/stevengum97/SO_Q43146320